# symfony2 not finding specified page

Tags: symfony, routes, silex

Test enviro: 
c:\apache
c:\php

Two files: 
c:\apache\htdocs\greeting\web\index.php
c:\apache\htdocs\greeting\app\app.php

http://localhost/greeting/web/index.php     displays "Default page"

http://localhost/greeting/web/hello         displays "Not Found, The requested URL /greeting/web/hello was not found on this server."

index.php contents:

```
<?php
    $website = require_once __DIR__.'/../app/app.php';
    $website->run();
?>
```

app.php contents:

```
<?php
    require_once __DIR__."/../vendor/autoload.php";

    $app = new Silex\Application();

    $app->get("/", function() {
        return "Default page";
    });

    $app->get("/hello", function() {
        return "Hello page!";
    });

    $app->get("/goodbye", function() {
        return "Goodbye page!";
    });

    return $app;
?>
```

What am I missing here?  Any help would help this frustrated beginner.

Cheers,
Ayden

Comment: Did you already try adding a .htaccess? And did it work?

Answer (score 1):

You didn't mention any server-configuration, so I'm guessing you forgot to configure the **.htaccess**:

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    Options -MultiViews

    RewriteEngine On
    #RewriteBase /greeting/web
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
    RewriteRule ^ index.php [QSA,L]
</IfModule>
```

If you are using some other server than Apache or if you want more explanation, you can look at the [Silex Webserver Configuration Documentation](http://silex.sensiolabs.org/doc/web_servers.html#webserver-configuration) for further information.

Comment: Yes, you're probably right, it might be a problem with the redirections. To try it I recommend to insert the front controller in the URI like so: http://localhost/greeting/web/index.php/hello